# Run a CI job only if another manual job was triggered

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` with 2 deploys and a job to check that the deployed APIs are reachable.

```
stages:
  - deploy-stage
  - deploy-prod
  - check

service:stage:
  stage: deploy-stage

service:production:
  stage: deploy-prod
  when: manual

check:stage:
  stage: check

check:production:
  stage: check
  dependencies: service:production
```

At the moment, even though the specified `dependencies`, I'm having the `check:production` running **even when** the `service:production` job is *skipped* (I did not manually trigger it).

I *could* add `allow_failure: false` to `service:production`, so that `check:production` is not run (indirectly, because the whole pipeline gets halted), but I would prefer a way to **express more explicitly the direct dependency of `check:production` → `service:production`**.

---

*How to configure `check:production` to run **automatically, only when** `service:production` was manually triggered?*

Comment: Why not just repeating the `when: manual` condition in `check:production`? No need to specify a dependency in this case… BTW your stages do not match the defined ones.

Comment: Thanks, the config was an example, I fixed the stage names & removed `dependencies`

Comment: Using `when: manual` would require 2 manual clicks (deploy + check). My question is about how to avoid this and have depending jobs to run automatically after a single manual trigger. E.g. think if those depending jobs would be 4: I'd need to do 5 manual clicks, making the pipeline less automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `needs` keyword to state that one job needs another.

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy-stage
  - deploy-prod
  - check

service:stage:
  stage: deploy-stage

service:production:
  stage: deploy-prod
  when: manual

check:stage:
  stage: check

check:production:
  stage: check
  dependencies: service:production
  needs: ['service:production']
```

In this example, `check:production` won't run if `service:production` has failed, is a manual job and hasn't been run yet, was skipped, or was cancelled.

`Needs` can also be used to tell jobs to run before other, unrelated jobs from previous stages finish. This means that `check:production` can start once `service:production` finishes, even if `service:stage` is still running.

Here's the docs for more information on this and other keywords: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

You can use the `dependencies` keyword for similar results, but if the other job fails or is an untriggered manual job, the dependent job will still run, and might fail depending on the outcome of the first job. `Needs` is a newer, and improved option.